# ORDER BY problem when I use 2 queries in one

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `mytable`.`date` DESC
```

So I select all the content and order it by date and it  works. Now I want to make a query in side the query like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `mytable`.`date` DESC) test
```

I just select * from the first query. But the order is not by date. Why?
And I do I solve this? I do not want to order it outside the test-query with the ().

Comment: Because order by inside the subquery is ignored and result of subquery is always returned as an unordered set so there is no use of order by inside subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You use `order by` in the outermost query.  Period.

SQL tables and results sets represent *unordered* sets, with the one exception of when a result set has an explicit `order by` in the outermost query.

Those are the rules of SQL; it is how databases work.

Comment: I wanted to GROUP BY product with the outer query. So all the newest rows where selected for each product (group by selects the first row when I do not use SUM). Is there another fix to select the newest row for each product?

Comment: Would you mind adding some more details in your post such as the table schema details along with sample input dataset along with expected output. The more details you provide, easier it is to provide a more accurate answer.

Comment: @MacQwerty . . . What you are trying to do is not proper SQL.  Ask a new question with sample data and desired results and a clear explanation of what you want to do.